# An error occured when use dotnet ef migrations - No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, database-migration

I face this error when I try to do the EF migration on my ASP.NET Core project.

The command I executed is:

```
dotnet ef migrations add "InitialMigration" -o Data/Migrations
```

This is the error I get:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring'method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext

This is the `Program.cs` code

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.

        builder.Services.AddControllers();

        builder.Services
            .AddInfrastructureServices(builder.Configuration);

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

And here is the `DbContext` code:

```
public class AuctionDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AuctionDbContext()
    {
    }

    public AuctionDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuctionDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Auction> Auctions { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the `DependencyInjection` class

```
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        if (connectionString is null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
        }

        services.AddDbContext<AuctionDbContext>(option =>
        {
            option.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
        });

        return services;
    }
}
```

I tried different solutions:

- Add a parameterless constructor to the `DbContext` class
- Moved the whole logic inside `Program.cs` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was solved by overriding the OnConfiguring Method and manually add the ConnectionString here

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("YourConectionString");
        }
    }
```